# how to set a Window on the top only one time?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi, mfc

I am writing a program that firstly shows Java GUI using JNI and then calls Windows simple GUI.

IF I call Windows simple GUI without calling Java GUI, it shows on the top of other windows so I can see it directly right after it starts.

the problem is, if I call Windows simple GUI after calling JAVA GUI, it shows its windows simple GUI at bottom of other windows: other Windows just hide it.

Here is a picture, you cam see my simple Windows GUI has been hide by visual studio when it starts.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understood the question but I am going to try to answer anyway. What I understand is that you are launching 2 programs and you want to bring one of them to the front of the desktop.

I suppose that you are using [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to start the programs. There are flags that you can set in the [STARTUPINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure (*wShowWindow*), so see if you can use that.

Otherwise you can try calling [ShowWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) after launching both programs (and possibly waiting for the Java program to start). You will need to pass the window handle to this function.

You can obtain the window handle by calling [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), checking the executable file name for each window using [GetWindowModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633517%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Pseudo code:

```
foreach window in EnumWindows()
    if GetWindowModuleFileName(window) == "program.exe"
        ShowWindow(window, ...)
```